# Що таке "бо гуля тепло" у пісні "Промінчики", в реченні "Мені краще чуть, бо гуля тепло"?

Tags: значення-слів

З пісни "[Промінчики](https://youtu.be/eUlNmuPDzxA?si=46y3uuxHbrX9Z92v)" гурту Дно:

> Вітамінчик Де
> Вітамінчик тут
> Сонечко несе
> Квіточки цвітуть
> Мені краще чуть
> **Бо гуля тепло**
> Прооомінчики б'ють
> Прямо у є**о

Що таке "бо гуля тепло"? Гуля = "заокруглена опуклість, наріст на тілі людини або тварини від запалення, удару тощо" чи ні?

Отже, значення фрази – "я відчуваю тепло в місці гули"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Це зазвичай дитяча [якщо замість інфінітіва, тут за контекстом теж підходить] форма до *гуляти* або *гульби*.

> <sub>Великий тлумачний словник сучасної мови</sub>
>
> [гу́лі](https://slovnyk.me/dict/vts/%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96)
>
> 2. *невідм., дит., розм*. Те саме, що *гуляти*.

Answer (score 2):

Я бачу цьому два пояснення.

1. В українській мові (зокрема в поезії, або піснях) деякі дієслова в 3-й особі однини теперішнього часу в закінченнях -ає, -яє можуть втрачати останній голосний:
   *Як за роботою вільна неволенька груди щораз дотика* (замість "дотикає");
   *Тихий день догора* (замість "догорає");
   *Дніпрова бистрина мов промовля* (замість "промовляє") тощо.
   "Гуля" можна віднести до таких слів, а в форму 3-ї ос. од. тепер. ч. його ставить іменник "тепло", утворюючи інверсію ("тепло гуляє" -> "гуля тепло").
2. Найімовірніше. Оскільки текст сприймається на слух, можливо там просто збіг м'якого "ть" з твердим "т" ("Мені краще чуть, бо гулять тепло"). В піснях зазвичай виспівуються голосні, а приголосні закінченя глушаться практично до зникання.

P.S. Цікаво, що з усього цього глибокодумного й логічного тексту питання виклика(є) лише це...

P.P.S. А  "заокруглена опуклість, наріст на тілі людини або тварини від запалення, удару тощо" пишеться і вимовляється через "ґ" ("[ґуля](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D2%91%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F)").